# Is there a way to add a react app in an iframe in Salesforce? It would helpful if I get other approaches as well

Tags: iframe, salesforce

I am trying to integrate my react app into salesforce, I am not sure about the approaches available however, I have tried with iFrame tag. Seems there is CORS issue. Not sure whether salesforce allows this kind of integration.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <script>
   <iframe src='xxxx://www.test.net'/>
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas was created for use cases just like this

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm